# Killing multiple process by process name using shell script

Tags: shell-script, process, kill

I am having a shell script, which will start processes and kills the process. It is accepting the processes names as arguments. Need to find the `pid` and kill those.

Initially, it was like

```
for procname in ${@};do
    pkill -f $procname
done
```

Idk why, it is not killing all the processes passed to it. Now, I'm looking something like this

```
for procname in ${@};do
  IFS=$"\n"; echo
    (ps auxw | awk -v proc="$procname" -v preserve="${0##*/}" \
       '$0 ~ proc && $0 !~ preserve && ! /awk/ { print $2}')
done
```

I'm trying to print the pid in above code, but I need `kill` command and it should be good, if it works without for loop

> > process names will contains `.` like `com.abc.def.pqr.xyz`

Comment: If your script is also starting the processes, why don't you save the PIDs so that you easily can terminate them later?

Comment: Yes, that can be possible. But these arguments are coming from Java. So, It will decide which process needs to kill or which process won't

Comment: Does the code as posted actually run? The parser should refuse the assignment  to `$procname`

Comment: @StephenBoston My bad, I didn't copy pasted the code. Corrected now... :)

Answer (score 4):

`pkill -f -- "$regex"` kills processes whose arg list (for those processes that executed a command, or have an ancestor that did) joined with spaces (same as reported by standard `ps -f` or BSD `ps u`) matches the given extended regular expression (always excluding itself).

So all you need here is to join the positional parameters with `|`:

```
IFS='|'
pkill -f -- "$*"
```

To match on process names instead of arg list, remove the `-f`. Note however that on Linux, the length of process names is limited to 15 bytes, so can't possibly be `com.abc.def.pqr.xyz`. Also note that `.` is a regular expression operator that matches any single character, so to match process arg lists that contain that (and not `comXabcYdefZpqr+xyz` as well for instance), you'd need a `com\.abc\.def\.pqr\.xyz` regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate @Stéphane Chazelas answer. Since I am getting arguments for this shell script from `JAVA` and they are space separated and they contain character `.` in process names. I figured it out like this..

```
temp=()
for procname in ${@}; do
    temp+=$(jps -ml | grep $procname | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1 " "}')
done
kill -9 $temp
```

Comment: `java` may invoke a shell to interpret some shell code such as `yourscript name1  name2`, where those process names are indeed space-separated, but that's just because it happens to be that in the shell language, space is used to delimit command arguments. Your  script will not receive the process names *space separated* it will receive them as different arguments (`$1`, `$2`...) and `"$*"` can be used to join those arguments with the first character of `$IFS`.

Comment: Your code would only work in the `zsh` shell. In ksh93/bash, you'd need to quote all the variables and also use `temp+=( "$(...)" )` instead of `temp+=$(...)` which for those shells would be the same as `temp[0]+=$(...)`. In zsh, you can also use `${(j[|])argv}` to join the positional parameters with `|` without having to modify `$IFS`.

Comment: Note that the `re` in `grep` stands for `r`egular `e`xpression, so `.` would still be treated as a regexp operator there.

Comment: as long as that `jps .. | awk` pipeline outputs just a process id number, it should work in Bash (in the usual cases) even with using `temp` as a scalar and relying on word-splitting. But then the `temp=()` initialization is confusing, as you're _not_ using `temp` as an array here.

Comment: @ilkkachu, Ah, I hadn't seen the `" "` appended at the end of awk's output. Yes, then `$temp` (same as `${temp[0]}`) would then be subject to split+glob in bash as it's not quoted, and assuming `$IFS` contains the space character and doesn't contain digits, it should work.

Comment: @ilkkachu I am using `temp` as an array and appending each `pid`(with space) to `temp` in for. Then at last, I am sending those `pid`'s to `kill` command

Comment: @ShashankGb, ... well, yes. That's not an array, that's a string. You are _initializing_ `temp` as an array (with `temp=()`) and then only using the first element of the array. That's what the comments above tried to tell you. There is a difference, and you're only getting away with it because your values don't contain whitespace so you can rely on word splitting without messing everything up. You could remove the initial assignment, or change it to just `temp=`. Or heck, you could change it to `temp=( '' foo bar )`, and it'd still do the same. Assuming Bash for the whole time, of course.

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas \@ilkkachu Gotcha !!! lots of info, thx